# Gremlin command line cannot run any :plugin or :install commands

Tags: gremlin

i run gremlin on command line and all gremlin commands work fine when traversing a graph. i can do math and find vertices/edges and do queries, but when i try to see my plugins or install any or call ANY command beginning with a colon (:)  it throws this error:

```
gremlin> :plugins list
groovysh_parse: 50: unexpected token: : @ line 50, column 1.
   :plugins list
   ^

1 error
```

the stack trace is:

```
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:302)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:106)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:148)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:119)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:131)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:359)
at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:142)
at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:236)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit$parse.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.RigidParser.parse(Parser.groovy:148)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.RigidParser$parse.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Parser.parse(Parser.groovy:67)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Parser$parse.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:139)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:114)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell$leftShift$0.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:88)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1079)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:128)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:148)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:100)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:137)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:57)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1079)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:128)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:148)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:66)
at com.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.console.Console.<init>(Console.java:60)
at com.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.console.Console.main(Console.java:102)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can recreate your problem pretty easily if I execute the `:plugin` command against the 2.x version of Gremlin Console.  `:plugin` is a new command for TP3.  Are you sure that you are using the right version?

```
         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
plugin activated: tinkerpop.server
plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities
plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph
gremlin> Gremlin.version()
==>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Your console should look something like the above to use the `:plugin` command.

Comment: \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(_)-oOOo-----
10:17:44 WARN  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader  - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
gremlin> Gremlin.version()
==>2.5.0
gremlin>

yup, looks like i need the newer Gremlin console. thanks Stephen. that was making me crazy (now I just have a whole bunch of other crazy stuff to deal with.  Titan's docs are not very good)

Comment: You may yet find inconsistencies in Titan docs if you are using the 0.9 milestone releases that support TinkerPop 3.x.  That release is not official yet and the docs are likely behind.